# IOS local notifications always appear when I enter background

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, local, schedule

```
This is code

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // calendar1 
       NSCalendar * calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
       NSDateComponents * Datecomps1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
       [Datecomps1 setDay: 12];
       [Datecomps1 setMonth:03];
       [Datecomps1 setYear: 2017];
       [Datecomps1 setHour: 23];
       [Datecomps1 setMinute: 59];
       NSDate *MyDate1 = [calendar dateFromComponents:Datecomps1];
       [self addToSchedult:MyDate1];
    }

    - (void)addToSchedult:(NSDate *)date {
        UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        UILocalNotification* localNotifi = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        if (localNotifi) {

        NSLog(@"date:%@",date);
        localNotifi.fireDate = date;
        localNotifi.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotifi.repeatInterval = 0;
        localNotifi.soundName = @"";

        [app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotifi];
        }
    }
```

How can I do?

I have a problem with local notifications.
I set two dates to Schedule and local notifications, 
It is work on time about my date.
But when I enter to background every time, this two notifications will appear to screen.
How can I cancel it? And let two local notifications only appear on time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solve this problem.

If I Add previous time add To local notifications , While I enter to background it will appear to screen.

So should check this date is previous time or not, if it's previous time did not add to local notifications.